# Can websocket server disconnect a client?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm using **node.js** with the **socket.io** module.  I have a need to disconnect a websocket client on occasion.  Can I do this forcibly from the server, or does the server have to "ask" the client to disconnect?

Note. From the server I've tried **socket.end()** which works from the client, but not on the server side.